# how to implement adsense codes in magento

Tags: blocks

I pasted an Adsense code in static block. Script shows up on website in the left sidebar where the ad should be. Can someone explain what I need to do in order to get the Ads working?

Comment: Can you be more precise on your all configuration ? Which code are you using ? Which JavaScript ? Thank you.

Comment: Since I'm not so computer adept, I don't really  know how to answer that. I have live ecommerce site thegiftedbaby.com. You can see the script on all pages starting with "all products" page.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source code it seems that you have a bad encoding for your tag [image]
That means the script calling Google Adsense is not correctly parsed by your browser.
Can you explain how did you call that code in your page ?

Answer (score 0):

Someone else set it up for me and Is this possibly it?

I must have erased some of the characters by mistake. Is it possible thart you list the steps?